# How do to customize height to Daisy UI steps?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3, daisyui

I am trying to build a multi step from in react with Daisy UI and tailwind css 3.

I have set up a grid system for the form.

```html
   <div className="grid grid-cols-12  gap-4">
        <div className="col-span-10 grid">
         ....
       </div>
         
        <ul className="steps steps-vertical col-span-2">
          <li className="step step-primary">Basic Details</li>
          <li className="step">Add image</li>
          <li className="step">Confirmation</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

With this the form looks like this.
[image]

I want the `2 Add image step` to be down and not take up equal space. How do I do that in tailwind css?

I tried using grid rows but it breaks the layout.
[image: breaking layout]

Comment: have you tried something like `mt-24` that could do it

Comment: yes, I tried that on the first `li`. Does no have any changes